# If condition array declaration error inside input tag for php and datatable code

Tags: php, json, datatable

I am new to PHP. I'm trying to fix the syntax error for PHP code. But seems not working. I'm getting the syntax error at s[i][4]. If I change to "+s[i][4]+" it is not complaining about syntax error but it is not reading the actual value. I think I'm using the wrong variable inside PHP code but tried lot ways but failed. Actually I'm trying to hide paid button if the status(s[i][4]) is cancelled. Please help.

## Java script code

```
`<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var table  = $('#myTransactionitems').dataTable();  //Initialize the datatable
                var user = $(this).attr('id');
                if(user != '') 
                { 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'transactions',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(s){
                            console.log(s);
                            table.fnClearTable();
                            for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                                table.fnAddData([
                                    s[i][0],
                                    s[i][1],
                                    s[i][2],
                                    s[i][3],
                                    s[i][4],
                                    s[i][5],
                                    "<form method='post' action = 'donationSplit'><input name = 'donationid' type='hidden'\
                    value='"+s[i][0]+"'></input><input type='submit' value = 'Paid' <?php if (s[i][4]=='Cancelled'){ ?> style='display:none' <?php   } ?> class='btn btn-sm btn-success pull-left '>\
                   </input></form><form method='post' action = 'donationSplit'><input name = 'donationid' type='hidden' \
                    value='"+s[i][0]+"'></input><input type='submit' value = 'Cancel' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right'>\
                   </input></form>" 
                                ]);                                     
                            } // End For

                        },
                        error: function(e){
                            console.log(e.responseText);    
                        }
                    });
                }   
            });

        </script>`
```

## Trasaction.php code

`

```
<?php
include('sessionstart.php');
include('session.php');
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$user_id=$_SESSION['login_user_id'];
$query = mysql_query("select * from mytransactions_list where userid = '$user_id'");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $output[] = array($fetch[0], $fetch[1], $fetch[2], $fetch[3], $fetch[4], $fetch[5], $fetch[6]);
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
`
```

Comment: 1. please format your question. 2. what's the error you get? 3. It seems that you're using mysql_* which is deprecated. consider using mysqli instead.

Comment: `<?php if (s[i][4]=='Cancelled')`...` aren't you mixing PHP and JS variables? Reading your code, `s[i][4]` is a JS-variable, right? You can't use JS variables in PHP.

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't use the `mysql_*`-functions, since they have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead and use Prepared Statements to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should work fine. I have added a JS variable named `disp1`. It's assigned the value of "display:none;" if the `if` condition is matched, otherwise it will be blank.

```
for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    var disp1 = '';
    if ( s[i][4] == 'Cancelled' ) {
        disp1 = 'display:none;'
    }
    table.fnAddData([
        s[i][0],
        s[i][1],
        s[i][2],
        s[i][3],
        s[i][4],
        s[i][5],
        "<form method='post' action = 'donationSplit'><input name = 'donationid' type='hidden'\
                    value='"+s[i][0]+"'></input><input type='submit' value = 'Paid' style='" + disp1 +"' class='btn btn-sm btn-success pull-left '>\
                   </input></form><form method='post' action = 'donationSplit'><input name = 'donationid' type='hidden' \
                    value='"+s[i][0]+"'></input><input type='submit' value = 'Cancel' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right'>\
                   </input></form>" 
                            ]);                                     
                            } // End For
                        },
                        error: function(e){
                            console.log(e.responseText);    
                        }
                    });
                }   
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a Javascript variable in PHP because PHP code is executed first.

Try this

```
"<form method='post' action = 'donationSplit'>\
    <input name = 'donationid' type='hidden' value='"+s[i][0]+"' />\
    <input type='submit' value = 'Paid' " + (s[i][4]=='Cancelled') ? "style='display:none'" : "" + "class='btn btn-sm btn-success pull-left ' />\
</form>\
<form method='post' action = 'donationSplit'>\
    <input name = 'donationid' type='hidden' value='"+s[i][0]+"' />\
    <input type='submit' value = 'Cancel' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right' />\
</form>"
```

Comment: Alexis:Instead of hiding the button it always displaying style='display:none'